# not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) File AAPL_volume.txt not found , try again

Tags: python

```
# method which reads the trade volumes and returns two lists
def readFile(filename):
    try:
        day, trades = [[], []]
        fil = open(filename)
        lines = fil.readlines()
        # iterate the read lines
        for line in lines:
            # split the lines and append the values to list
            a, b = line.split()
            day.append(a)
            trades.append(float(b))
        # finally return the list
        return day, trades
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        print("File {} not found , try again".format(filename))
        exit(0)


# methdo to get the max and min trades Index
def getMaxMinTrades(trades):
    # initially assume max and min are at index 0
    maximum, minimum = [0, 0]
    for t in range(len(trades)):
        if trades[t] > trades[maximum]:
            maximum = t
        if trades[t] < trades[minimum]:
            minimum = t
            # return the index
    return maximum, minimum


# methdo to find the average trades
def getAverageTrades(days, trades):
    feb, march = [[], []]
    for i in range(len(days)):
        if days[i].split("/")[1] == "02":
            feb.append(float(trades[i]))
        else:
            march.append(float(trades[i]))
    return sum(feb) / len(feb), sum(march) / len(march)


# make call to get the days and trades
days, trades = readFile('AAPL_volume.txt')
# find the maximum and minimum trade volumnes
maximum, minimum = getMaxMinTrades(trades)
# display the result
print("{} has the maximum trade value of {}".format(days[maximum], trades[maximum]))
print("{} has the minimum trade value of {}".format(days[minimum], trades[minimum]))

# make method call to get getAverageTrades
febAvg, marchAvg = getAverageTrades(days, trades)
print("The average trade volume of February is {}".format(febAvg))
print("The average trade volume of March is {}".format(marchAvg))
# finally display the greatest average
print("AAPL has higher trading volume in {}.".format("March" if marchAvg > febAvg else "February"))
```

here, it is showing
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
File AAPL_volume.txt not found , try again(this message I have generated in case file no found.)
i have added a valid path for the txt file, still, it is showing an error.
I have added comments to the code also.

Folder Structure
[image: Folder Structure]

file.txt

Date,Volume
1/02/2022,86213900
2/02/2022,84914300
3/02/2022,89418100
4/02/2022,82465400
7/02/2022,77251200
8/02/2022,74829200
9/02/2022,71285000
10/02/2022,90865900
11/02/2022,98670700
14/02/2022,86185500
15/02/2022,62527400
16/02/2022,61177400
17/02/2022,69589300
18/02/2022,82772700
22/02/2022,91162800
23/02/2022,90009200
24/02/2022,141147500
25/02/2022,91974200
28/02/2022,95056600
1/03/2022,83474400
2/03/2022,79724800
3/03/2022,76678400
4/03/2022,83737200
7/03/2022,96418800
8/03/2022,131148300
9/03/2022,91454900
10/03/2022,105342000
11/03/2022,96970100
14/03/2022,108732100
15/03/2022,92964300
16/03/2022,102300200
17/03/2022,75615400
18/03/2022,123511700
21/03/2022,95811400
22/03/2022,81532000
23/03/2022,98062700
24/03/2022,90131400
25/03/2022,80546200
28/03/2022,90371900
29/03/2022,100589400
30/03/2022,92633200
31/03/2022,103049300

file.txt image
[image]

Comment: Full traceback please! And at best a ss of your folder structure

Comment: And make sure your cwd is the parentdirectory of your file

Comment: i have added the project structure. @NoBlockhit

Comment: Thank you, are you sure your cwd is correct?

Comment: yes, i am using pycharm IDE@NoBlockhit

Comment: i have added the file.txt(AAPL_volume.txt). please Help

Comment: Remove try/except while debugging, it will tell you which line is giving you the problem

Comment: Did you try passsing the full path of the .txt file to the `readFile` function?

Comment: @GiovanniTardini There is a better way, try using the traceback builtin module: `traceback.print_exc` And dont use `Exception`, rather `FileNotFoundError`

Comment: thanks @GiovanniTardini I found the error and solved it.

Comment: thank everyone for your input.

Comment: if I want to find the maximum trade value for February and march separately, how would i do

Comment: what about just passing the days of feburary/march to your function?

Comment: can you help me out with this@NoBlockhit

Comment: Does your file really look like that or is it more like a CSV?

Comment: it is a txt file@LancelotduLac

Comment: It's a text file in CSV format. Have you considered using the *csv* module?